# how to add c++11 support to syntastic vim plugin?

Tags: vim, c++11, syntastic

I am using syntastic in my c++11 project. When I am editing in vim, and save (:w) the syntastic plugin gives me errors on every initializer list {} and for each loops which are clearly c++11 features that it's missing.

I installed syntastic using pathogen.

Here are two examples of the error I am getting on initializer lists and for each loops (both c++11 that compile fine):

[image: error on initializer lists] 
[image: error on for each loop]

Comment: What is the output of `:echo b:clang_user_options` command from a buffer belonging to the project? If your assumption is correct, there will be no `-std=c++` substring.

Comment: The output of `:echo b:clang_user_options` is `-I/usr/include -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`. So I don't understand why I'm getting the errors related to initializer lists and for each loops. I'll add an example error to the main post.

Comment: Turns out this is **not** clang_complete, this is syntastic. I will update the post and the answer.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Turns out the C++ linter (syntax checker) of syntastic has many options that can be set on your .vimrc (unfortunate, I wish it was project specific, like the .clang_complete solution).

To enable c++11 standards and use the libc++ library with clang (which is what my project is using) I added the following lines to my ~/.vimrc

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler = 'clang++'
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'
```

it now works beautifully.

Comment: As I checked clang++ and g++ options are identical, I replaced "clang++" with "g++", but it still not working

Comment: I don't think you can run g++ with -stdlib=libc++ though.

Comment: I tried without -stdlib=libc++ too, but that wasn't successful either

Comment: Actually I compiled without -stdlib, but put -stdlib in .vimrc, when normal settings weren't successful

Comment: make sure you have clang!! For me all errors all together just wouldn't appear, then I realized I needed to install clang =P

Comment: For me I have to remove `-stdlib=libc++` to make it working

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem and **I insist to process c++98 and c++11 separately**. below is my solution:

create file named **gcc.vim** under **bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/cpp11/** and copy these to it:

```
"============================================================================
"File:        cpp11.vim
"Description: Syntax checking plugin for syntastic.vim
"Maintainer:  Gregor Uhlenheuer <kongo2002 at gmail dot com>
"License:     This program is free software. It comes without any warranty,
"             to the extent permitted by applicable law. You can redistribute
"             it and/or modify it under the terms of the Do What The Fuck You
"             Want To Public License, Version 2, as published by Sam Hocevar.
"             See http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/COPYING for more details.
"
"============================================================================

if exists('g:loaded_syntastic_cpp11_gcc_checker')
    finish
endif
let g:loaded_syntastic_cpp11_gcc_checker = 1

if !exists('g:syntastic_cpp11_compiler')
    let g:syntastic_cpp11_compiler = executable('g++') ? 'g++' : 'clang++'
endif

if !exists('g:syntastic_cpp11_compiler_options')
    let g:syntastic_cpp11_compiler_options = '-std=c++11'
endif

let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

function! SyntaxCheckers_cpp11_gcc_IsAvailable() dict
    return executable(expand(g:syntastic_cpp11_compiler))
endfunction

function! SyntaxCheckers_cpp11_gcc_GetLocList() dict
    return syntastic#c#GetLocList('cpp11', 'gcc', {
        \ 'errorformat':
        \     '%-G%f:%s:,' .
        \     '%f:%l:%c: %trror: %m,' .
        \     '%f:%l:%c: %tarning: %m,' .
        \     '%f:%l:%c: %m,'.
        \     '%f:%l: %trror: %m,'.
        \     '%f:%l: %tarning: %m,'.
        \     '%f:%l: %m',
        \ 'main_flags': '-x c++ -fsyntax-only',
        \ 'header_flags': '-x c++',
        \ 'header_names': '\m\.\(h\|hpp\|hh\)$' })
endfunction

call g:SyntasticRegistry.CreateAndRegisterChecker({
    \ 'filetype': 'cpp11',
    \ 'name': 'gcc' })

let &cpo = s:save_cpo
unlet s:save_cpo

" vim: set et sts=4 sw=4:
```

that will make gcc checker available (want other checker? you can do the similar things i did for yourself) for files with &filetype == 'cpp11' in vim. how to make your files automatically recongnized as cpp11 filetype in vim? just create file named **ext_detect.vim** under **~/.vim/ftdetect/** with the following content:

```
au bufnewfile,bufread *.cpp11 set ft=cpp11
au bufnewfile,bufread *.cppx set ft=cpp11
```

by this way, you can process your *.cpp files as c++98 standard and *.cpp11 or *.cppx as c++11 standard separately, not only syntax checking, but also syntax highlighting (if you need cpp11 syntax highlighting support, [this vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3797) will be useful, although not perfect).

Answer (score 4):

It has project specific options, like the .clang_complete solution

You can set path to files g:syntastic_cpp_config_file and g:syntastic_c_config_file. The default is .syntastic_cpp_config for C++. Put file in root of the project and compiler options inside it (one for each line)

for [details](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C--%3A---gcc)

Answer (score 0):

If your using YouCompleteMe in addition to Syntastic you need to change your .ycm_extra_conf.py file. Sepcifically change '-Wc++98-compat' to '-Wnoc++98-compat'.

I didn't have to change the Syntastic settings myself, although that might be because I'm using a compile_commands.json file.

[via here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim-syntastic/x8f7XSTFxw8).

Answer (score 0):

If you use YouCompleteMe,maybe you should change '.ycm_extra_conf.py'.only change flags:(file path~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py) ;

```
 flags = [
 '-std=c++11',
 '-O0',  
 '-Werror', 
 '-Weverything', 
 '-Wno-documentation', 
 '-Wno-deprecated-declarations', 
 '-Wno-disabled-macro-expansion', 
 '-Wno-float-equal', 
 '-Wno-c++98-compat', 
 '-Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic', 
 '-Wno-global-constructors', 
 '-Wno-exit-time-destructors', 
 '-Wno-missing-prototypes', 
 '-Wno-padded', 
 '-Wno-old-style-cast',
 '-Wno-weak-vtables',
 '-x', 
 'c++', 
 '-I', 
 '.', 
 '-isystem', 
 '/usr/include/',
 ]
```