# C++11 functions not recognised in vim

Tags: vim, c++11, syntastic

While using a few c++11 functions in vim I noticed that the vim plugin <del>taglist</del> syntastic keeps reporting errors such as `'stoi' was not declared in this scope`.

So I have a few questions,

- How do I get <del>taglist</del> syntastic to recognise c++11 functions?
- Is there a way I can at least hide the error messages within vim?

Also I know I can replace c++11 specific code with standard c++ to fix the errors, but I want to find out if there is another way.

---

Edit: Sorry, turns out syntastic is actually responsible for the errors not taglist
Thanks for reminding me, I have too many plugins and I forget what each do

Comment: Taglist doesn't understand anything to your code. The indexing is done by ctags so you should rewrite your question to take that into consideration. And maybe do a a bit of search on your own about ctags and C++11.

Comment: This message is not emitted by `taglist`. It looks like a `gcc` message. Identify plugins that invoke `gcc` and configure them to use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Did you try Googling for "syntastic c++11"?  When I try, it turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158772/how-to-add-c11-support-to-syntastic-vim-plugin which might help.

Comment: @benjifisher Yep i just figured out the same solution as the one suggested in that post, was just editing the question with the answer, thanks

Comment: you should add the solution as an answer, not as an edit of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searching on syntastic's git repo I found an easy solution,
by adding `let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = '-std=c++11'` in to my .vimrc